# window.open opens up blank page IE9

Tags: javascript, tabs, null, popup, window.open

gPopupwin = window.open(url, popName, arguments, false);

where gpopwin return null and `window.open` opens up a blank page.

I have 7 tabs to show in the popup, on click of each link on the main page, one by one popup gets added. When I click on the second link before opening the popup(click on the first link). This throws a blank screen. once blank screen comes up. it will not populate the second popup.
[Popup window on click of each link on the main page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTYY5.png)

Comment: If window.open returns null, most likely a pop-up blocker has done its job.

Comment: it doesn't happen all  the time. only When if you click on second link before popup is opened. because content of second link should go as second tab in popup.

Comment: The code, we need to see the code, without the code it's not possible to say anything ... See how to create [mcve].

Comment: thank you. i removed popup blocker. it seems to be working. We use different framework where it loads aspx pages.